# Magento 2 - Soap Authroization Problem

Tags: magento2, soap-api-v2

I get this error when I tried to use soap with the following piece of code.

Error

```
Uncaught SoapFault exception: [env:Sender] Consumer is not authorized to access %resources in ...
```

PHP

```
$wsdlUrl = 'http://local.magento.com/soap/default?wsdl&services=customerAccountManagementV1';
$opts = array('http' => array('header' => 'Authorization: Bearer n95e7at5r0wf6mj1xv6ynni62d4xbkfi'));
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$soapClient = new SoapClient($wsdlUrl, ['version' => SOAP_1_2, 'context' => $context]);
$serviceArgs = array("customerId" => 1);
$soapResponse = $soapClient->customerAccountManagementV1IsReadonly($serviceArgs);
var_dump($soapResponse);
```

The token is correct and there is no problem when I test it using soapUI.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You can use below working example and try to follow the provided
>   Magento 2 SOAP service consuming code piece.

In the below example i have taken `GetDefaultBillingAddress` and passed `customerId" => 1` to get the customer default billing address.

**Example**

Create a file in you Magento root (`http://local.magento.com/soap.php`), paste below code with your file paths, token and load the file in browser.

```
  require('vendor/zendframework/zend-server/src/Client.php');
  require('vendor/zendframework/zend-soap/src/Client.php');
  require('vendor/zendframework/zend-soap/src/Client/Common.php');

$token = '5proni6r27e34uywnem5orgu4jstgw3d';

$wsdlUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1/m5agento207/soap/default?wsdl&services=customerAccountManagementV1';
$opts = ['http'=> ['header' => "Authorization: Bearer " .$token]];
$context = stream_context_create($opts);

$soapClient  = new \Zend\Soap\Client($wsdlUrl);

$soapClient->setSoapVersion(SOAP_1_2);
$soapClient->setStreamContext($context);

$slide = array("customerId" => 1);
$result = $soapClient->customerAccountManagementV1GetDefaultBillingAddress(array("customerId" => 1));
var_dump($result);
exit;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It works. But I don't understand. What is the difference between your code and my code? Is it because of the zendframework?