# Data format for creating a product using soap api in magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, soap, magento-2.1.4

```
$productData = array(
        'sku'               => 'MSD',
        'name'              => 'MSD',
        'visibility'        => 4, /*'catalog',*/
        'type_id'           => 'simple',
        'price'             => 5,
        'status'            => 1,
        'attribute_set_id'  => 4,
        'weight'            => 1,
        'custom_attributes' => array(
            array( 'attribute_code' => 'category_ids', 'value' => ["3"] ),
            array( 'attribute_code' => 'description', 'value' => 'Simple Description' ),
            array( 'attribute_code' => 'short_description', 'value' => 'Simple  Short Description' ),
            ),
    );
```

and passing data like below

```
$result = $soapClient->catalogProductRepositoryV1save(array('product' => $productData));
```

I got this error 
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [env:Sender] Invalid product data: %1 in D:\xampp\htdocs\magento214\vendor\zendframework\zend-soap\src\Client.php:1116 Stack trace: #0 D:\xampp\htdocs\magento214\vendor\zendframework\zend-soap\src\Client.php(1116): SoapClient->__soapCall('catalogProductR...', Array, NULL, NULL, Array) #1 D:\xampp\htdocs\magento214\soap5.php(34): Zend\Soap\Client->__call('catalogProductR...', Array) #2 {main} thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\magento214\vendor\zendframework\zend-soap\src\Client.php on line 1116

Comment: `extension=php_soap.dll` is Enabled?

Comment: @AnkitShah it is enabled .Passing the same data with REST it worked .Can you help me out..

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/128223/magento-2-soap-authroization-problem
http://webkul.com/blog/magento-soap-api/

Comment: thanks but it does not help as my access token and soap authorization both working fine,having error in product data @AnkitShah

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `attribute_set_id` with `attributeSetId` and `type_id` with `typeId`:

```
$productData = array(
    'sku'               => 'MSD',
    'name'              => 'MSD',
    'visibility'        => 4, /*'catalog',*/
    'typeId'           => 'simple',
    'price'             => 5,
    'status'            => 1,
    'attributeSetId'  => 4,

...
```

Comment: How to send 'qty' => '30.0000' Please?